# Flash CC publishig for Android - How to change APK installation icon?

Tags: android, air, apk, flash-cc

My question is how to change default APK installation icon (not the one onto desktop after installing the app). I need to change the default green robot icons which I see while regular browsing of apk's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating an AIR application, both Android and iOS icons are all stated under the `<icon>` tag in your `yourapp-app.xml` file.

You just need to make sure **all sizes are stated**, and your icon will appear both in the installation APK icon and on the device screen.

Here are all the sizes you need to define in your `yourapp-app.xml` file:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/25.0">

    ....

    <icon>
        <image36x36>assets/icon_036.png</image36x36> 
        <image48x48>assets/icon_048.png</image48x48> 
        <image57x57>assets/icon_057.png</image57x57> 
        <image72x72>assets/icon_072.png</image72x72>
        <image76x76>assets/icon_076.png</image76x76> 
        <image96x96>assets/icon_096.png</image96x96>
        <image114x114>assets/icon_114.png</image114x114>
        <image120x120>assets/icon_120.png</image120x120>
        <image512x512>assets/icon_512.png</image512x512>
    </icon>

    ....

</application>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Only one problem I have with 192 pix icon. Compiler says "Unexpected or unknown element or attribute in the application descriptor file. Application.icon.image.192x192 is an unexpected element/attribute." I double checked that icon and it's everything fine with it. I just deleted line with 192x192 icon from descriptor xml and everything went fine.